# 8 in thimble, 6 in pipe

Tags: insulation, heating, ducts

I just installed a wood stove in the addition I built for my trailer. My father-in-law insisted on going and buying me an 8 inch thimble for my stove pipe to run through the wall. My stove pipe is only 6 inch diameter so I have a two inch Gap all around it that I can see straight outside. It lets a lot of heat out and cold in.

What can I fill this gap with that will not burn my house down?

[image][image]

Comment: `feel this Gap` ... what does feeling the gap mean?

Comment: filling it up sorry I want the gap to be gone

Comment: fiberglass batting should work .... you could also insert a 6" thimble if it will fit

Comment: You might be asking "the wrong question". That single-wall pipe cannot be installed within 18 inches of combustible structure (including gypsum, studs, ceiling, etc), meaning you either need to remove 18 inches of wall (if not also ceiling) around it and put in non-combustible, or obtain properly engineered shielding, or you need a different kind of pipe.  NFPA 211 is a good place to start.